# PHP Fatal error: Class 'Phalcon\Script\Color' not found

Tags: phalcon

I'm running Ubuntu Server 12.10 and have installed phalcon like this

```
sudo apt-get install php5-dev php5-mysql gcc git-core
git clone git://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon.git
cd cphalcon/build
sudo ./install
```

then I've added

```
extension=/usr/lib/php5/20100525/phalcon.so
```

to php.ini which located in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini and restarted apache2. If I execute

```
<?php print_r(get_loaded_extensions()); ?>
```

I can see that the phalcon extension is loaded. Then I've installed phalcon-devtools like that

```
git clone git://github.com/phalcon/phalcon-devtools.git
cd phalcon-devtools
sudo ./phalcon.sh
```

and restarted apache2. No errors were shown during that operations, but when I'm trying to execute

```
phalcon commands
```

I get an error like this

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Phalcon\Script\Color' not found in /home/user/phalcon-devtools/phalcon.php on line 84
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was in php.ini for CLI, which is located in `/etc/php5/cli/`, after I added `extension=/usr/lib/php5/20100525/phalcon.so` there, I was able to use Devtools. Thanks to @NikolaosDimopoulos

Answer (score 1):

Official documentation is a bit confusing so try this:

I think this is a problem of extension not loaded

After successfully compile steps:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-dev php5-mysql gcc git-core 
git clone git https://github.com/Phalcon/cphalcon.git
cphalcon cd/build 
sudo ./install
```

Create a new file called "**30-phalcon.ini**" 
and within it call the extension Phalcon with this single line:

```
extension=phalcon.so
```

save the file and copy the folder `"/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d /"` and `"/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/"`

restart the server: `sudo service apache2 restart`

While the devtools do this:

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/phalcon/phalcon-devtools /var/www/devtools
```

then create a symbolic link to run via terminal:

1: `sudo ln -s /var/www/devtools/phalcon.php /usr/bin/phalcon`

2: `sudo chmod ugo+x /usr/bin/phalcon`

3: `type "phalcon" in the terminal and see if it's work.`

it should work now: D

Answer (score 0):

I always install the devtools from the PEAR channel

```
pear channel-discover pear.phalconphp.com
pear install phalcon/Devtools
```

You might get an error that the Devtools are not in stable mode but (as of the time of this writing) you can use this command:

```
pear install phalcon/Devtools-0.5.0
```

[Source](http://pear.phalconphp.com)

Comment: I tried to use pear, but got the following  
`sudo pear install phalcon/Devtools-0.5.0  
phalcon/Devtools requires PHP extension "phalcon"  
No valid packages found  
install failed`

Comment: That tells me that phalcon is not installed as an extension according to your system. Check the php.ini for your CLI environment as well.